# How to find the limit of $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[1-\frac{t^2 r^k \sqrt{1-r}}{2}+o\left(t^2\right)\right]$ as $r\rightarrow 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question is to find the limit of $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[1-\frac{t^2 r^k \sqrt{1-r}}{2}+o\left(t^2\right)\right]$ as $r\rightarrow 1$ and intuitively it would be $e^{-kt^2}$ for some $k\in R$ and am not sure how to approach here. Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: Hi. By exchanging limits with continuous functions I would start by taking the logarithm. Since $\ln(1+x) = x + \mathcal{o}(x)$ you end up summing: $\sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \left(-\frac{t^2}2 r^k\sqrt{1-r} + \mathcal{o}(t^2, r^{2k})\right)\approx -\frac{t^2}2 \frac r{\sqrt{1-r}}+\sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \mathcal{o}(t^2, r^{2k})$. I am not sure how you would treat that sum over $\mathcal{o}(t^2, r^{2k})$. Then exponentiate and you'd at least get to a guess for $k$.

Comment: That is a good idea, let me take a stab at it. Thanks!